# Rollback in Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: entity-framework-4, foreign-key-relationship

i have a Customer class which includes a Contact class that stores all the contacts for that particular customer, so they are linked with a foreign key relationship.

Here is my scenario: the user Edits the customer's info including the contacts, and then decides to hit the "Cancel" button. The contacts are bound to a grid so everytime an edit/add/delete is made it automatically updates the Contact entity in the cached database context. So how can i rollback all the changes made by the user to the Contact entity?

I tried the following (after searching google for answers):

```
    public static void CustomerRollback(Customer customer)
    {
        dbContext.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, customer);
        dbContext.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, customer.Contacts);
    }
```

But that didn't work. Any other ideas? Please note that my problem is only with rolling back the Contacts entity. I guess what's causing the issue in the first place is that the grid automatically updates the cached entities. So when i try to cancel, the EntityState for each contact has already changed to a modified state (EntityState.Added, EntityState.Deleted, etc.). Do i need to loop through the contacts and check their EntityState property and do something with it?

Thanks
Caesar

Comment: The context is intended to be a unit of work. The way to "roll back" work is to dispose the context. It sounds like you are keeping the context around too long. This has far-reaching, negative consequences.

Comment: Both u and Devart below suggested disposing the context, but doesn't that mean that i would have to re-fetch all the data from the database? That would hinder performance.

And by the way, it's not an issue of having the context around too long because this problem occurs early on when I start the application. And i'm the only user testing it, so no concurrency issues either.

Comment: You are prematurely optimizing. Your long-term performance is probably already poor if you're using a singleton context. Instead of rejecting correct practices because of imagined performance implications, use the context the way it's intended to be used and then fix any performance issues via profiling and point fixes.

Comment: Thanks Craig, i would really appreciate a link for a good dependable tutorial. I can't seem to find good ones out there. I come from a NHibernate background and i'm just starting to figure out EF 4.0. It seems so easy in theory but the quirks and undocumented problems are a major frustration. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You use an ObjectContext in EF just like you use a Session in NH. It's almost the same idea. In both cases they're a unit of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what i did, which is a workaround trick from Entity Framework 1.0, i was hoping that EF 4.0 has a much simpler way to rollback the object context. Please share with me if you know of a better way, this seems to work for the time being:

```
        // delete added objects that did not get saved
        foreach (var entry in dbContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added))
        {
            if (entry.Entity != null)
                dbContext.DeleteObject(entry.Entity);
        }
        // Refetch modified objects from database
        foreach (var entry in dbContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified))
        {
            if (entry.Entity != null)
                dbContext.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, entry.Entity);
        }
        // Recover modified objects that got deleted
        foreach (var entry in dbContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted))
        {
            if (entry.Entity != null)
                dbContext.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, entry.Entity);
        }

        dbContext.AcceptAllChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [AcceptAllChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.acceptallchanges(VS.90).aspx) method. [SaveChanges(SaveOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395500.aspx) can also be helpful. 
One more solution is to use the ObjectContext instance as Unit Of Work and to create it for an operation, and to save changes only when necessary (when user confirms that it is necessary) just disposing the context in another case - this will discard the changes made to the context.

Comment: But if i dispose the context then i'll have to re-fetch all the data back again for the rest of the application...that would be bad.

I will google your suggestion about the Unit of Work.

Thanks